# I am not able to connect the eclipse with tata cdma proxy setting 172.23.252.15 port 9401

Tags: eclipse

I am using tata cdma conection for net surfing with proxy setting 172.23.25.15 port 9401.
when it came to work on eclipse, it could not connect with internet. please help me what will be the host name in the tata cdma netwok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to configure Eclipse to use the same proxy as your browser is using - the same details as you have given. See [How to configure proxy settings in Eclipse](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/).

Comment: what will be the host name in the eclipse network setting for 172.23252.15 port 9401. network provider is tata cdma

Comment: You can use the IP address as the hostname.